# Is there a plugin that pushes posts to your Google+ profile?

Tags: plugins, google-plus

A Google+ equivalent to Simple Twitter Connect that pushes every post you make to your G+ profile - does such a plugin exist?

Comment: I think this should be tagged google-plus, but I can't create tags.

Comment: No, Google hasn't released enough of an API yet to write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a plugin does not yet exist because Google does not have a public API that allows for such third party integrations.